# compiling gradle project with hibernate throws package does not exist error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, gradle

I am trying to compile a Java Spring Boot MVC app using Gradle 3 and it keeps giving me this error: `package org.springframework.orm.hibernate4 does not exist` when I try to import various classes in my files. I have specifically  added `compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'` in my dependencies part of my build.gradle file so I assume that this dependency provides my project with the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4` package. I am keen to debug this problem but I can't see any obvious errors in my code or build file. I tried to check if the missing package is in the ~/.m2 directory path but I cannot find it. In fact, there are no jar files in the ~/.m2 directory so I think that cannot be the issue as the compiler only complains about hibernate4. Any support is appreciated.

Cheers

AHL

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {




    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    // end::jetty[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]
    testCompile("junit:junit")

    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.6.Final'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.31'
    compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
    compile "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3"
    compile "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.7.13"


}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs "src/main/resources"
        }
    }
}
```

Spring Boot Application.java:

```
package com.concretepage;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Comment: No, a hibernate jar won't provide a spring class. How about showing your build file?

Comment: Hi JB. I have added the build file. Cheers.

Comment: You're missing the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa (or at least the spring-orm library, but I would definitely use spring-data-jpa).

Comment: I added this line `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")` to my build.gradle file and now it compiles. But when I run `./gradlew build && java -jar build/libs/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar` then Spring boot doesn't start. I.e. it builds but the server does not start.

Comment: I was expecting the server to start but it did not. It just builds and then goes back to the command line prompt. Why doesn't the server start?